# Azure worker role.Sharepoint client sdk

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2013, azure-worker-roles, sharepoint-clientobject

I am using azure worker role and sharepoint 2013 client components to access sharepoint lists and process them.
It works on development environment but when i upload to azure cloud service.
It cannot create clientcontext. and I get the error.

Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

I have installed sharepoint 2013 client components by remoting to worker role machine.

this is worker role hence can't implement solutions with app pool permissions :|

Any help would be great!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.

For anyone who needs to access registry or tasks which require permissions.this might be helpful

just add following line to worker .csdef file, workerrole tag

```
<Runtime executionContext="elevated"></Runtime>
```

That should do it.